# How to keep a button behind virtual keyboard?

Tags: react-native

When the virtual keyboard appears, I want to keep the button behind it, not jumping up to the top of the keyboard. How to achieve this? Here is the layout I have:

```
<>
<FlatList />
<Button />
</>
```

Comment: Editing windowSoftInputMode in AndroidManifest.xml as android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" seems to be working but is that the right solution?

Comment: do you want button to move up above keyboard?

Comment: No, it's located at the bottom of the screen and I want to keep it there.

Answer (score 0):

This way the button will stick on the bottom

```
<View style={{flex:1}}>
  <FlatList contentContainerStyle={{flex:1}}/>
  <Button />
<View/>
```